# Mongoose populate array by ref not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose

I'm working on a simple anagraphic system and i have a customer with the following data model:

```
    const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
      emails: [
        {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "email",
        },
      ],
      name: { type: String },
      surname: { type: String },
      avatar: { type: String },
      firm_role: { type: String },
      vat_number: { type: String },
      fiscal_code: { type: String },
      address: { type: String },
      birth_date: { type: Date },
      notes: { type: String },
    });
const emailContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customer: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "customer" },
  label: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  creation_date: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
});
module.exports = {
  Customer: mongoose.model("customer", customerSchema),
  Email: mongoose.model("email", emailContactSchema)
};
```

I use the following mongoose find procedure to get the customer and the associated emails:

```
    const customers = await Customer.find({ user: req.user.user_id })
        .skip(10 * parseInt(req.params.page))
        .limit(1)
        .populate("emails")
        .exec();
```

Everytime i run this code i get the customer data but the email array is always empty.

Can you help me?

Comment: Print the `customer` and check if there is a `emails` array containing ObjectId element?

Comment: When i print the customer the email array is present but empty

Comment: That means there are no associated emails with the customer.

Comment: Actually i got the reference, this is my customer `_id: 6463ae3c256530ee218c584f`, and inside my email collection i have one record with field 'customer' with it's object id `customer
6463ae3c256530ee218c584f`. But when i find with mongoose the customer using populate the email is still empty.